# Excellent WordPress unix hosts with SSH access?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

My boss is sick of DreamHost's excuses.  We have a popular WP site on a Unix VPS with DreamHost.  We'd like to find a new, more reliable host, who can handle <s>a high-ish</s> traffic of perhaps 2000 uniques a day WP site and offers SSH access.

Anyone have a recommendation?

Comment: Peoples' idea of "high-ish traffic" is going to vary. Can you provide some numbers to go along with that, for context? Also are you looking for a VPS in particular(with all the control/maintenance responsibility), or just a more reliable host?

Comment: Thx for the reply; it's averaging 800 - 1,000 visitors per day  according to Google Analytics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As much as I personally dislike Dreamhost and encourage you to leave anyway on principle, I'm not sure this is really a hosting issue. I see a few major options:

1. Dreamhost's VPS plans really, *really* suck.
2. Someone customized the VPS config and messed something up
3. Your WordPress templates are incredibly inefficient and/or something in the WP config(eg. inefficient plugins) is responsible.

I'm leaning toward the second two. That's just not enough traffic that the number in and of itself should be taking out a server; there has to be more going on.

If you still want a recommendation, I like [WebFaction](http://webfaction.com). I have a WordPress client on their cheap plan with easily 15x the traffic you're inquiring about and have never seen a significant problem. Technically it's shared hosting, but you have almost as much access as a full VPS, if you happen to need to compile stuff and whatnot. (You didn't say whether VPS was a requirement.)

Comment: Dreamhost has admitted to us that they have serverside issues which are cuasing us downtime.  Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh I don't even know how to respond to them flat out admitting they're just broken. Usually it's more like "Nope, we see no problem. Guess there's not a problem! Here's a 'funny' semi-contextual piece of stock photography."

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you should go for a VPS, it'll give you more control over things. I'm using Linode.com, they give 512 mb ram vps for just $20/month and that server will be able to handle the traffic easily.

Now, the issue is that you'd have to setup everything on your own - php, mysql, apache/nginx or whatever you want. Personally, I would suggest that if you want to install then use NGINX as it works flawlessly with WordPress and is lot better than apache in terms of performance.

You can install NGINX, PHP, MYSQL, APC [opcode caching] using [this script](https://github.com/vladgh/VladGh.com-LEMP/blob/master/README.mkd). It'll install quickly and then you will have to configure a little and it'll be good to go!